# Auto answer with google video call?

Tags: empathy, pidgin, google-chat

Does any one know any way to set up auto-answer for google video calls on an Ubuntu machine? I don't care which client is used (Empathy, Pidgin, in-browser, anything else, etc.), and I don't care how hacky it is (as long as it doesn't take more than a couple of hours to set up).

For concreteness, by auto-answer I mean that all incoming video calls are automatically answered, with a two-way voice and video connection.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this does not answer the question exactly as written, but being the OP, I know that it's close enough. The trick I was was to use google hangouts instead of google video calls as follows:

Create a circle which includes those people you want to allow to call the machine. Start a hangout for this circle on the machine you wanted auto-answer on. Now everyone in the circle will be able to start video communication with this computer.